# Module location issue

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

Does anyone have any idea as to what this error means in Xcode?

```
unable to resolve module `./outputs/App`
```

This is from a project that I have not previously worked on so I'm just trying to run it for the first time.

I found the line in index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './outputs/App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
```

Any help is welcome! As you can tell I'm new to React Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check where your App.js is located inside the project and import it with the correct path in index.js and your project should work fine